# Snorkeling vs diving with a breathing cylinder

Tags: pressure, water, fluid-statics, air

If diving with 5m snorkeling pipe our lungs would collapse due to 0.5 atm difference, right?

If diving with a cylinder that has air with atmospheric pressure (the pressure our lungs can use), we can be no problem at 5m even though there would 0.5 atm difference, right?

Where is the hole in the reasoning?

I think the cylinders don't have 1 atm air inside. But now how our lungs can use this high pressure air?

Comment: 10 m adds 1 full atmosphere of pressure, not 0.5 atmosphere.  Also, full air tanks in the U.S. are pumped up to a pressure of 3000 psig.  And note - if the pressure in the air tank is not higher than ambient pressure, you can't get any air out of the tank.

Comment: oh yeah! Sorry, was trying out different numbers and forgot to change it to 5m :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a [regulator valve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_regulator) that ensures that the cylinders deliver air at the pressure at your current depth.

Comment: Indeed, that was the key invention that made SCUBA possible.

Comment: OK! I see, great. That is what I was looking for! However does anyone know, how our lungs can "use" this high pressure? It certainly evolved on land where there is 1 atm pressure.

Comment: It's the pressure difference the lungs experience, not the absolute pressure. But you can not change the pressure too fast, since it takes the little cells time to get more air in or out.

Comment: @trula in fact (as you probably know),  decompression on the way back up has to be very slow, because the  human body transfer systems are slow to release the compressed gases from remote tissues to the lungs.  Fast decompression produces large bubbles in **very bad places**  .  Hence "the bends."